# NGINX URL redirect matching a specific rule

Tags: nginx

I am not new to nginx but unfortunately never understood well the redirect/rewrite rules.
I have a dilemma and already tried what I know with no success.

What I want is a simple URL rewrite/redirect, when I type in browser bar:
https://example.com/chart.php?id=1234
the URL to automatically transform into the following and ofc showing the same content as original:
https://example.com/chart/1234

I already tried in many ways ex:

```
location /chart/{
      rewrite ^chart/([0-9]+)/?$ chart.php?id=$1 break;
      proxy_pass  _to_apache;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, the example you have has the regex and the replacement backwards.  The first is what matches in the browser, the second is where you want to go.  Also: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: rewrite ^/chart.php?id=([0-9]+)/?$ /chart/(.*)$1 last;   Already read that page, like I said, everything I tried is not working: no effect. nginx -V 2>&1 | tr -- - '\n' | grep  _module
http_ssl_module
http_v2_module
http_realip_module
http_image_filter_module         I can't see here http_rewrite_module installed/enabled. Maybe this should be the root cause? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All URIs in Nginx begin with a leading `/`, which is missing in both the *regex* and *replacement* in your `rewrite` statement.

So this block:

```
location /chart/ {
    rewrite ^/chart/([0-9]+)/?$ /chart.php?id=$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

will pass `/chart/123` upstream to `http://example.com/chart.php?id=123` - which is opposite to your stated requirement.

---

To pass `/chart.php?id=123` upstream to `http://example.com/chart/123` you would use:

```
location = /chart.php {
    rewrite ^ /chart/$arg_id? break;
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

[location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) use a *normalised* URI which does not include the query string. The arguments in the query string are available as `$arg_` variables.

Comment: Hello, The redirect works just fine, thank you but the problem is that is not displaying anymore properly that page. Looks like the apache running the web application behind can't handle correctly the URI request...What I want is the URL to be formatted as you suggested [ok] but the displayed page to be exactly the same [not ok].

Comment: Then you need to see what resources are not loaded properly and change references to those in the original application.